# CRM 2011 Field Security - data owner

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom field with security field enable also I configure security profile to allow manager to view/update this field but I also need to allow the owner of the entity field to view / update this field.
Which in my case a field in account & contact entity.

I tried a couple of plugins found it on my search by I don't know how to get it work:

```csh
public void ShareSecureFieldWithOwner(Entity record)
{
// Any method that helps you find the AttributeMetadata Id
var attributeId = FindSecuredAttribute();

if (attributeId != Guid.Empty)
{
    var userAccess = new PrincipalObjectAttributeAccess
                         {
                             AttributeId = attributeId,
                             ObjectId = record.ToEntityReference(),
                             PrincipalId = record.OwnerId,
                             UpdateAccess = true,
                             ReadAccess = true
                         };

    context.AddObject(userAccess);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance & appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that mail problem is **var attributeId = FindSecuredAttribute();** line. Have you written that method already?

Comment: no i found this code while i search on google but really i don't know how to create a plugin, i give it a couple of try with Visual Studio 2010 but it keep show's alot of errors while debugging.

it would be highly appreciated if you can help done this. 

regards,

Comment: So may be you will start from simple plugin and then will switch to something complex like this?